# It is possible that the WorksheetChangeEvents function misses Events while running itself?

Tags: excel, vba

I am struggling with the mechanics behind the Worksheet Change Event function in VBA. I have written the following script:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim NewPrice, OldPrice
Dim intersection As Range
Set intersection = Intersect(Target, Range("B:B"))
OldPrice = Target.Value

If Not intersection Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
        NewPrice = .Value
        Application.Undo
        OldPrice = .Value
        .Value = NewPrice
    End With

    *Do something* 
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The macro takes 0,04 seconds to run. Whereas this is pretty low, there are almost 200 values in Range("B:B"). All these cells represent tickdata of stocks, so they change a lot.

*Question 1*: what happens when this macro runs, for example sparked by a change in Cell B4, and, while running, a different cell in column B changes? Will this macro run again and, more importantly, each time a cell changes?

*Question 2*: will other cells in column B change in the first place? Because my macro includes the following lines

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
Do something
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

These lines are necessary, because the script will cause a loop otherwise.

I cannot find the answer in the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Worksheet.Change)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Application.EnableEvents = False` to help **NOT** trigger the `Worksheet_Change` Event while running code. So to answer your questions:

While `Application.EnableEvent` is set to `False` changes of cells will **NOT** trigger another run of the `Worksheet_Change` event. And **YES** you can still change cells values. Just try add a line like `Cells(1,2).value = "Test"` instead of do something and loop your code using `F8`.

Sidenote: You'r missing an `End if` :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Regarding your answer on question 1, it is essential that the script runs for each change. So, the only alternative is to create the exact same macro for each cell in column B (instead of column B as Target)?

Comment: You can’t make the final change after you set it back to true?